# Filter Queries which sum of their amount field are greater or lesser than a number

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

let's say this is my model :

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=23, decimal_places=8, null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=23, decimal_places=8)
```

i'm trying to get all the records which sum of their amount will be lesser than any integer i give.
for example from 20 records that exists , it returns first 5 records which sum of their amount is 1000 . it is like having these values : 100,400,300,100,100 . the sum is 1000 so it returns them as queryset.
it is possible to implement it with loops but i'm trying to handle it with django orm .

can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this using aggregate function [Sum](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/) from Django.

```
from django.db.models import Sum
amount_sum = Item.objects.filter(amount__lt=1000).aggregate(amount_sum=Sum("amount"))["amount_sum"]
```

However, The above Django query will have a equivalent SQL query as:

```
SELECT SUM("app_Item"."amount") AS "amount_sum" 
FROM "app_Item" 
WHERE "app_Item"."amount" < 1000; args=(Decimal('1000'),)
```

Comment: this is not what i'm looking for

Comment: [<Item: 1, 100 >,<Item: 2, 100 >,<Item: 3, 100 >] . i want this queryset out put bcuz i want the sum of amounts to be = 300 for example . and as u can see the output has what i want .

Comment: Oh well, Just to be clear, do you need the queryset along with the sum of the amounts annotated?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`Window`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) functions to run a cumulative sum per row, ordered by the primary key like this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Window


Item.objects.annotate(
    cumulative_sum=Window(
        Sum('price'),
        order_by=F('id').asc()
    )
).filter(cumulative_sum__lte=1000)
```

This will then return the first few item instances with prices that add up to less than or equal to 1000.

Comment: i got several errors like django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Window is disallowed in the filter clause   and also AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'filter'

Comment: just an edit for this answer . you have to remove Window . it causes errors  . just remove it and it will be fine . thanks for the answer @BrianD

Answer (score 0):

Gets all the items,
Create empty item_list,
Loop through all items,
If item amount is under 1000
append to item_list.

```
    items = Item.objects.all()
    item_list = []
    for item in items:
        if item.amount < 1000:
          item_list.append(item)
```

Comment: well as i told i wanna do it with orm . like Q , F , Sum , aggergate and anotate , etc . i know how to do it with loop . thanks anyway