# Solution to filter by Cumulative sum and error: Window is disallowed in the filter clause

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

This is follow-up to a question to:

[Filter Queries which sum of their amount field are greater or lesser than a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69372463/filter-queries-which-sum-of-their-amount-field-are-greater-or-lesser-than-a-numb/69375357#69375357)

which is supposed to be solved. Answer suggests using Window function with filter but this results in a error:

`django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Window is disallowed in the filter clause.`

Comment from *@atabak hooshangi* suggests removing the Window function, but query doesn't work in intended way after that. Any ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

let's say we have these 2 models:

```
class Developer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=False, 
        unique=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=False, 
        unique=True)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    cv = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_cv_location, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Developer'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Developers'
    ordering = ('first_name',)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'


class Skill(models.Model):
    developer = models.ForeignKey(to=Developer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(to=SkillCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
              null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    priority = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-priority',)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.name} skill of {self.developer}'
```

As you can see , we have a developer model which has relationship with skill. Each developer can have multiple skills.

now consider we want to get the developers whos sum of their priorities are greater than a number.

The orm query should work this way :

```
from django.db.models import Sum
developers = Developer.objects.annotate(tot=Sum('skill__priority')).filter(tot__gt=250).all()
```

The output will be the developers who has greater than 250 priority_sum .

You can filter tot which is an annotated variable in any way you want.

like `.filter(tot__lte)`
or
`.filter(tot__lt)`

I hope this is what you were looking for.